# Omega squared for measure of effect in R?

Tags: r, anova, effect-size, split-plot

The statistics book I am reading recommends omega squared to measure the effects of my experiments. I have already proven using a split plot design (mix of within-subjects and between-subjects design) that my within-subjects factors are statistically significant with p<0.001 and F=17.

Now I'm looking to see how big is the difference... is there an implementation of omega squared somewhere for R (or python? I know... one can dream ;) Searching on the internet for R-related stuff is a pain the ***, I don't know how I manage to find stuff with C.

thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of such a function, but perhaps someone could look at the formulas in Olejnik and Algina  (2003) http://www.cps.nova.edu/marker/olejnik2003.pdf and write a function

Comment: @Jeromy Nice reference! This one is worth looking too: Recommended effect size statistics for repeated measures designs (BRM 2005 37(3)), http://j.mp/cT9uEQ

Comment: @chl Thanks. Apparently, ezANOVA() in the ez package in R reports generalised eta squared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function to compute omega squared is straightforward to write. This function takes the object returned by the aov test, and calculates and returns and omega squared:

```
omega_sq <- function(aovm){
    sum_stats <- summary(aovm)[[1]]
    SSm <- sum_stats[["Sum Sq"]][1]
    SSr <- sum_stats[["Sum Sq"]][2]
    DFm <- sum_stats[["Df"]][1]
    MSr <- sum_stats[["Mean Sq"]][2]
    W2 <- (SSm-DFm*MSr)/(SSm+SSr+MSr)
    return(W2)
}
```

edit: updated function for n-way aov models:

```
omega_sq <- function(aov_in, neg2zero=T){
    aovtab <- summary(aov_in)[[1]]
    n_terms <- length(aovtab[["Sum Sq"]]) - 1
    output <- rep(-1, n_terms)
    SSr <- aovtab[["Sum Sq"]][n_terms + 1]
    MSr <- aovtab[["Mean Sq"]][n_terms + 1]
    SSt <- sum(aovtab[["Sum Sq"]])
    for(i in 1:n_terms){
        SSm <- aovtab[["Sum Sq"]][i]
        DFm <- aovtab[["Df"]][i]
        output[i] <- (SSm-DFm*MSr)/(SSt+MSr)
        if(neg2zero & output[i] < 0){output[i] <- 0}
    }
    names(output) <- rownames(aovtab)[1:n_terms]

    return(output)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to recently report an $\omega^2$.

```
partialOmegas <- function(mod){
    aovMod <- mod
    if(!any(class(aovMod) %in% 'aov')) aovMod <- aov(mod)
    sumAov     <- summary(aovMod)[[1]]
    residRow   <- nrow(sumAov)
    dfError    <- sumAov[residRow,1]
    msError    <- sumAov[residRow,3]
    nTotal     <- nrow(model.frame(aovMod))
    dfEffects  <- sumAov[1:{residRow-1},1]
    ssEffects  <- sumAov[1:{residRow-1},2]
    msEffects  <- sumAov[1:{residRow-1},3]
    partOmegas <- abs((dfEffects*(msEffects-msError)) /
                  (ssEffects + (nTotal -dfEffects)*msError))
    names(partOmegas) <- rownames(sumAov)[1:{residRow-1}]
    partOmegas
}
```

It is a messy function that can easily be cleaned up. It computes the partial $\omega^2$, and should probably only be used on between-subjects factorial designs.

Answer (score 2):

I found an omega squared function in somebody's .Rprofile that they made available online:

http://www.estudiosfonicos.cchs.csic.es/metodolo/1/.Rprofile

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that generalized eta square is considered ([ref](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14664681), [ref](http://brm.psychonomic-journals.org/content/37/3/379.short)) a more appropriate measure of effect size. It is included in the ANOVA output in the [ez package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=ez) for R.

Comment: Actually, eta-squared is a highly positively biased statistic. It is, therefore, much worse in this situation than omega-squared, though because of its simplicity, it is more popular.

Comment: I agree with user above. Here's a link to back it up. http://daniellakens.blogspot.nl/2015/06/why-you-should-use-omega-squared.html

Answer (score 1):

Daniel "strengejacke" Lüdecke's package `sjstats` can not do omega-squared, partial-omega-squared etc for ANOVA models. Check it out.

Here is a vignette that demonstrates that:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjstats/vignettes/anova-statistics.html

```
install.packages("sjstats")
library(sjstats)

mod1 <- aov(y~x, data= d.frame)

anova_stats(mod1)
```