# Effect Size/Mean Squared Error from Linear Mixed-Model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, effect-size, sums-of-squares

I'm trying to report an effect size for a Linear Mixed-Model we've fitted in R. Right now I'm looking at reporting partial eta squared or eta squared. However, to do so I need to calculate the Sums of Squared Error. We're using the `lme()` function, which does not report MSE or effect sizes. I am not the one doing the primary analysis, so I don't know if we can switch to using the `ez` package, as described in [Omega squared for measure of effect in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/omega-squared-for-measure-of-effect-in-r).

The `lmeObject` returned by the `lme()` function has some information, but I am not sure which is the most appropriate. When using `anova()` on the `lmeObject`, it reports the denominator degrees of freedom for the F-test as 56683, so with a value for MSE I can calculate SSE and reverse-engineer the F-tests to get the SStreatments I need for partial eta squared. I have 2 fixed effects and one random effect (for a repeated-measures design).

I've looked at `lmeObject$sigma` and calculated the sums of the squares of `lmeObject$residuals[,1]`, but they don't agree (I'm squaring the `sigma` and dividing the SS by the degrees of freedom).

Any R masters out there that can tell how to calculate MSE or SSE from an `lmeObject`?

Comment: A comment in a now-deleted duplicate thread suggests an answer has appeared at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961349/r-partial-eta-squared-for-repeated-measures-anova-car-package.