# Get Summed Square Errors and Mean Square Errors from mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, anova, residuals, error

In R I ran a mixed  model using `lme()`, using `anova()` I get a **Type III ANOVA** table, however, in that table, I'm missing the residuals. I would like to estimate the fraction of variation explained by each explanatory variable but therefore I need the **Summed Square and Mean Error**. I have seen scientists reporting these fractions in my area of research from linear models, however, I would like to do the same for mixed models. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to this site! [This search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmixed-model%5D+lme+r-squared) (`[mixed-model] lme r-squared`) yields possibly interesting answers (about effect size in particular), in particular https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32248/930.

Comment: So I was just searching the wrong keywords! Thanks :)